# net use to connect a shared printer

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-vista, printing, net-use

I have a Windows 7 machine connected to a printer. I use another PC (in the same group) running Vista to connect this shared printer via COMMAND:

```
net use lpt2 \\Win7NAME\SHAREDPRINTERNAME /PERSISTENT:YES
```

I get the following error:

```
System error  64 has occurred 
The specified network is no longer available
```

Any Ideas or suggestions will be appreciated. Why could this error occur? How can I correct it?

Comment: the printer on? the computer the printer is connected to on? typo? can you ping the computer? just making sure...

Answer (score 0):

LPT2 is a local port not for TCP/IP

Ensure the printer is shared from the Windows 7 machine, then browse to the \Win7NAME and the printer will be there as a share.  Using Vista you can then just double click the printer to install.

Is there a specific reason for using command prompt for this?